# Exchange the strings and digits ordering in all lines of a file using regex shell command

Tags: regex, shell, perl

I have a file having data as follow. the data here is 0-64 and assigned with special character"=>". Expected output is shown below as well.

```
array databse
(
 user_content_1=>0
 no_entry=>1
 user_content_2=>2
 user_content_2=>3`
 left=>4
 ....
 )
```

I want output as follow.

```
array databse
(
  0 user_content_1
  1 no_entry
  2 user_content_2
  3 user_content_2
  4 left
  ....
 )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\w+)=>(\d+)/$2 $1/'
```

Example run with your test data:

```bash
$ cat dummy.txt
array databse
(
     user_content_1=>0
     no_entry=>1
     user_content_2=>2
     user_content_2=>3`
     left=>4
     ....
)

$ perl -pe 's/(\w+)=>(\d+)/$2 $1/' dummy.txt
array databse
(
     0 user_content_1
     1 no_entry
     2 user_content_2
     3 user_content_2`
     4 left
     ....
)
```

You'll have to work on the `\w+` and `\d+` if your real data contains more characters than what your example shows.

Comment: This is not working "perl -pe 's/\s+(\w+)=>(\d+)/ $2 $1/' filename"

Comment: Just inserted your test data into a file and it worked. Updated my answer to use a file instead of copy & paste

Comment: In case that your supplied test data is misleading and *does not* start with white space I have removed the `\s+` from my solution

Comment: @huuy, "not working" is not helpful: what *is* happening?